# How to populate data models with default data in Liferay?

Tags: database, liferay

I'm developing a portlet that is deployed as WAR. Database models are created by service builder. How can I insert initial data models to the database when the WAR is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the project a `portal.properties` file with the property:

```
application.startup.events=com.my.project.MyStartupAction
```

and impliment the startup import as extension of SimpleAction:

```
package com.my.project;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.SimpleAction;

public class MyStartupAction  extends SimpleAction {

    @Override
    public void run(String[] arg0) throws ActionException {
        if(startupDataNotExist()) {
            createStartupData();
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either as StartupAction, executed on startup of the plugin (read: during deployment AND during subsequent server starts) or as an UpgradeAction.

A good example for this is the sevencogs-hook that comes with Liferay CE and has the source code included. This is implemented as an UpgradeAction - e.g. on first start your database content will be "upgraded" to contain the sevencogs sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it with UpgradingProcess. [Here](http://www.liferay.com/web/ryan.park/blog/-/blogs/implementing-upgradingprocess-for-your-liferay-portlets!) are step-by-step instructions